# asp.net web api 405 method not allowed, post, custom action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've seen many question about the same issue, but i really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I receive a 405 error when I send a request to the InscricaoSecretaria/Salvar method.

Here is my config file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthorizationHandler());

        // Default Route Configuration

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Unity Container Configuration

        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<BusinessContext>(new InjectionConstructor(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HabileConnection"].ConnectionString));
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public class InscricaoSecretariaController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Salvar(InscricaoSecretaria inscricao)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the ajax call (angularjs). I am using the method named "salvar" of the angular module, which is fired with a button click.

```
"use strict";

(function(){
    var restClient = angular.module("restClient", ["ngResource"]);
    var serviceURL = "/habileapp/api/";

    restClient.factory("InscricaoResource", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
        return $resource(serviceURL + "InscricaoSecretaria", null, {
            "recuperar": {
                "method": "get"
            },
            "salvar": {
                "method": "post",
                "url": serviceURL + "inscricaoSecretaria/Salvar"
            },
            "finalizar": {
                "method": "post",
                "url": serviceURL + "inscricaoSecretaria/Finalizar"
            }
        });
    }]);
})();
```

The server responds with this error message:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.
```

**EDIT:**
Here are some request headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/habileapp/api/inscricaoSecretaria/Salvar
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Which method are you posting for? You should take a look at the http header, theres something messing up the requested URI.

Comment: @Fals I am using post :(

Comment: Do you post any data ? If so please provide sample data. Also make sure that AuhtenticationHanlder is not creating this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your webserver setup has been configured to handle the POST verb?  By default it should be setup for both GET and POST requests but it may have been changed at some point.  Below are some steps to check:

IIS:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

IIS Express:
Look in the applicationHost.config file in %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config folder.  Check that the ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0 handler is configured something like this verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE